# TV movie with a man on some mission for the devil and only person who recognizes him is a mute man

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

Set in mid 20th century rural America, a good looking but evil man is on some kind of mission of the devil, perhaps it was to kill a child soon to be born.  A key scene toward end of story is when several people (including him) are trapped in a fire inside a barn, but the evil man just smiles because the flames don't touch him, he has been granted indestructibility until he accomplishes the mission.  (His smile was captivating; it somehow reminded me of Senator Evan Bayh's good looks.)

The story ends as the evil guy stops at a farm house door and politely asks the woman of the house if she might have any odd jobs needing to be done.  She is pleased and starts to say yes, glad you came along, when a household servant (who recognizes the evil man for what he is) freaks out and gesticulates wildly but is mute so he cannot speak; he is rebuked by the woman and told to get back to his chores, while the evil guy smiles his beguiling smile again.   (What is the name of this?) Edit: (additional info)- I recall my dad was watching it with me, so it must have been before 2008.

Comment: Could be [American Gods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Gods_(TV_series)) - it's a series, but has similar themes?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Valorum, thanks, I did, and added the time constraint (on TV prior to 2008) after checking on @Bob's possible suggestion on Wikipedia -- that series premiered in 2017.